# String generator is printing two identical coordinates

Tags: java, android

I have created a MazeSolver android app for a school project. I am using stacks to hold the coordinate positions of the path taken to solve the maze. I have written this helper method to return the coordinates as a string, from cell (0,0) to the last cell of the solved maze.

```
private String generateSolutionString()
    {
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    while (!path.isEmpty())
    {
        String temp = path.top().toString();
        list.add(0, temp);
        path.pop();
    }

    String solution = "";
    boolean first = true;
    for (String s : list)
    {
        if (first)
        {
            solution += s;
            first = false;
        }
        solution += " " + s;
    }
    return solution;
}
```

I have also overridden the toString() method:

```
public String toString()
{
    return "(" + getX() + ", " + getY() + ")";
}
```

However, when it changes the statusLabel to the path, it is printing two (0,0) coordinates at the beginning. Why is it doing this?

Comment: What "statusLabel" are you talking about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you meant for

```
solution += " " + s;
```

to be `else`

```
else solution += " " + s;
```

Comment: Wow, I knew it was going to be stupid. Thank you. I have been staring at a screen for way too long today.

Comment: sometimes it just takes another pair of eyes